# javame: is it possible to disable highlight decrease and screen locking while my application is running

Tags: user-interface, java-me

I am developing a game where big pauses happen when no user actions (1-5 min).
I'd like the user can watch what happen in the game during those pauses.
Usual phone has 2 power-saving settings:

- light timeout (approx. 30sec)
- screen/keylock timeout (approx.1min)

May I disable those settings some way? Maybe by some MIDlet's attributes or by key pressed simulation... I don't know...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Impossible in JavaME.

For Nokia phones you can use Nokia UI API to do that.
Go to [Nokia Dev Library](http://library.developer.nokia.com/).
Then navigate:
Java Developer's Library 3.10 > Developer's guides > UI and graphics > Nokia UI API > Using Nokia UI API > Screen saver